# MySQL Stored Proc - Assign Variable to result rows from View

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

When developing a stored proc in MySQL how can I create a local variable that contains a result set of rows from a custom view?

```
SET temptable = 'view'; #non scalar value (rows)

#Perform multiple queries on view now

SET @a = (SELECT (...) FROM temptable WHERE ....);

SET @b = (SELECT (...) FROM temptable WHERE ....);

SET @c = (SELECT (...) FROM temptable WHERE ....);
```

I don't want to call the view each time I do a select statement since I feel its costly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all this. You can include all different conditions as `OR` condition (OR) use a `UNION ALL` query like

```
create temporary table tbltemp as
SELECT (...) FROM temptable WHERE cond1 or cond2 OR ... OR condn
```

Per your comment, depends; if you are trying to fetch scalar value then yes else no since more than one record can't be stored in a scalar variable. You will have to use `temp table` or a junction table.

You may need to edit your post and include more information as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I know this is the possibility. But is there a way to store table views as variables?

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing I would have to drop the table at the end of the stored procedure?

Comment: @BDillan, if it's temporary table then you don't have to since it's per session wise. Moreover why can't you just query the view directly? again, you can consider creating table valued UDF for this purpose. so multiple option present but can't say for sure unless know your actual requirement.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/DfYA4 - when calling my stored proc with temp table t1 it tells me the table already exists

Comment: I would query the view directly but I'm making multiple queries to the view. Moreover its not a set number of queries to the view Im making so I cant use OR. The view contains a couple ten thousands of rows.

Comment: @BDillan, my bad ... you are using MySQL. Ok in that case you can use `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS` and then followed by `create` statement

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on @Rahul's answer (don't have 50 rep), but check this out, it supports what he's saying: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-algorithms.html